# Named equivalent of W0703

Tags: python, pylint

I am trying to disable the pylint `W0703: Catching too general exception` exception within my python code using the inline disabling. I realize I can do the following (and it works fine):

```
# pylint: disable=W0703
```

But for clarity I would prefer to use the name instead of the cryptic code. I tried `catching-too-general-exception` but it just caused a `W0703: bad option value 'catching-too-general-exception'` (also tried a few variants but I am just guessing at this point).

I have also looked at [the wiki](http://pylint-messages.wikidot.com/all-messages) and it doesn't appear to include any name equivalent to the code.

1. Is there a named equivalent for disabling the W0703 message?
2. Is there a web page that shows the codes and their named equivalents?

Comment: (It's `broad-except`.)

Comment: Here is a list that covers a good number of codes with their name equivalents. 
 

https://codedb.app/docs/pylint-messages.html